# How can I Highlight cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel. I have two rows. In the first row there is highlighted cells and not highlighted cells. How do I match the highlight cells of the first row to the second row cells. I could just color the cell next to the highlighted cell but I have a lot of data. I would really appreciate your help.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you *Copy* the first row and *PasteSpecialFormats* onto the second row, hi-lighting in cells in the first rows will be transferred to the cells in the second row.